# Update record if checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, checkbox, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to check if the checkbox has been selected, and if so to then update all records where a particular column (`update_checkbox` - a boolean value in my table) is true.

The main aim is so only one record in the column can ever be 'true', and when a new record is created/edited and the checkbox checked then this record will be true and turn the other to false.

Under models/article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  if :update_checkbox == '1'
    #find records where update_checkbox is true & update to false
    Article.where(:update_checkbox => true).update_all(:update_checkbox => false)
  end
end
```

I can update my records fine but it's the 'if checkbox is checked' part I'm having trouble with - currently when I create a new record with `update_checkbox` checked the row with this flag set to true is not being set to false. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by  ActiveRecord `after_save` callback

```
after_save :reset_update_checkbox

def reset_update_checkbox
  Article.where(:update_checkbox => true).update_all(:update_checkbox => false)
end
```

`after_save` callback will run after create/update and reset your `update_checkbox` field to false.

**UPDATE**

Please consider this solution. Based on @index's asnwer

```
after_create :reset_and_update
after_update :reset_and_update if update_checkbox_checked?

def reset_and_update
  Article.where("id = ? and update_checkbox = ?", self.id, true).update_all(update_checkbox: false)
end

def update_checkbox_checked?
  self.update_checkbox
end
```

I'm pretty sure it will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That works... mostly :) but I'd like to maintain the current record as true while setting all others as false. Also this does not check if the checkbox is true/checked so all records will be updated to false either way (not what I'm looking for).

Comment: I've changed `after_save` to `before_save` which solves the first problem. Still looking for a way to check if checkbox is checked.

Comment: @LKB didn'n understood that you need to keep existing record with `true`. In that case please have a look on @index's answer. It will keep existing record with `update_checkbox = true`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a callback and do something like this:

```
after_save :reset_and_update if update_checkbox_checked?

def reset_and_update
  Article.where.not(id: self.id).update_all(update_checkbox: false)
end

def update_checkbox_checked?
  self.update_checkbox
end
```

`after_create` would just update all the other records to `false`. Whilst `after_update` would check first if `update_checkbox` is true and update all aside from self to `false`.

Test the data using this:

```
def update_checkbox_checked?
  puts "this checkbox value is #{self.update_checkbox}"
  puts self
  self.update_checkbox
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I gave it a go and it is replacing the previous `update_checkbox` values to false, but it's doing it if the new record's checkbox is true *and* false.

Comment: It seems that the checkbox check is being completely ignored. Any idea?

Comment: Do you create the record with `update_checkbox` as `true` by default?

Comment: It's false by default - `t.boolean  "update_checkbox", default: false`. It's strange because it seems the `reset_and_update` function is called no matter `update_checkbox` value.

Comment: A so it should apply to even create? Check my update if that fits. Only one would be true right, all would be false except the last one checked?

Comment: That's correct, only one record will be true at a single point in time (the last one checked), the rest should be false. The updated code still has the same issue. Hm...

Comment: Hrmn... Weird. That should exclude the last record cause of the `not` part. Can you check the sql generated by the `Article.where...`?

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with the `where` statement, just that it runs no matter the checkbox state.

`SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 72]]
UPDATE "articles" SET “update_checkbox” = 'f' WHERE ("articles"."id" != 72)`. According to this checkbox is either a '1' or '0' - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box so maybe I should check for '1' instead of true/false?

Comment: `if` should receive `true/false`. Maybe just keep checking what's the value inside `update_checkbox_checked?` like checking what `self.update_checkbox`'s value is and go from there.

Comment: How can I print the value to console? (Sorry I'm new to Ruby!)

Comment: Updated answer to add `puts` for console. See lowest section.